# How do I calculate neighborhood contiguity in R?

Tags: r, spatial, neighbours

My end goal is to calculate join counts, using the function `joincounts.multi()` from the R package `spdep`.

I have a very large raster file (nrows = 19663, ncols = 34073), with cell size of 30 m. It is a binary raster with two values, 0 and 1 (and many NoData cells). It is in integer format.

First I need to generate an `nb` object - that is, a list of neighbors. There are various ways to do this with this package. For polygon data, one uses the `poly2nb` argument. For grid cells, one uses the `cell2nb` argument. Apparently the latter does not function for very large rasters - it crashes my computer, and a Google search indicates others have had the same problem.

EDIT: I have decided to do this function over much smaller grids. I have all the grids in a folder and want to loop through to run this on each. I'm having some problems though. Here is my code:

```
#set working directory
setwd("C:/Users/myData/")

#get a list of all the raster files in that folder
ingrids <- list.files(getwd(), pattern=".TIF$", full.names=FALSE, recursive=FALSE)

#loop through each raster file, dropping the file extension and giving a unique filename to each, and doing the "cell2nb" function on each. 
for (i in 1:length(ingrids)){
    fileName <-strsplit(ingrids[i],split="\\.")[[1]][1]
    outputFile<-paste(fileName, '_nb','.tif',sep='')
    mydatanb <- cell2nb(17,17, type="rook", torus=FALSE)
    mydataout <-writeRaster(BETUPAPnb, filename=outputFile, overwrite=TRUE)
}
```

I get the following error message:

```
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : unable to find an inherited method for function ‘writeRaster’ for signature ‘"nb", "character"’
```

I would greatly appreciate any help trying to figure out this looping problem!

Comment: nb file? What is cell2nb? Is it in a package? Is it something you calculate? What is the definition? If the error can not be recreated, it is much harder for others to assist.

Answer (score 1):

The function `cell2nb` generates a list of neighbours for a grid of cells. Passing `mydata` is incorrect, and this is what is generating your error. Here are the parameters it expects:

```
> cell2nb
function (nrow, ncol, type = "rook", torus = FALSE) 
{...}
```

You do need to supply it with number of rows and number of columns. You can use `summary.nb` on an object created by `cell2nb` to see details of object it returns.

Comment: Thank you Rusan, I did also try it your way but it seems to crash. I will try it again however.

Answer (score 0):

I made an incorrect assumption about what the output of the cell2nb function would be. It is not a raster so the WriteRaster tool will not work. The function creates an "nb" object which is then called in other functions as is.

The other key piece of information is that it is that the cell2nb function is not dependent on a particular raster dataset - i.e., on a particular spatial arrangement. Instead, it creates an nb object based on a user-specified extent (the extent of your raster data that you call in later to use with the nb object after it has been created).